# Given iid $w_1,\ldots,w_N \sim N(0,1/d)$ iid, find a simple matrix $A$ s.t $\|aa^T-A\|_{op} \to 0$, where $a_i := E_{G \sim N(0,1)}[f(\|w_i\| G)]$

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices, measure-concentration

Let $d$ and $N$  be two large comparable integers, for example assume
$$
N,d \to \infty, \quad d/N \to \gamma \in (0,\infty).
$$
Let $w_1,\ldots,w_N$ be iid from $N(0,(1/d)I_d)$ and let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be such that $|f(x)| \le \exp(cx^2/2)$, for all $x \in \mathbb R$ and for some $c < 1$. Note that this implies $f \in L^2(\mathbb R,N(0,1))$. Define an $N \times N$ random matrix $T$ by
$$
T_{ij} := \zeta_0(f_i)\zeta_0(f_j),
$$
where the function $f_i:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is defined by $f_i(x) := f(\|w_i\|x)$, and $\zeta_k(h)$ is the (probabilist's) $k$th Hermite coefficient of a function $h \in L^2(\mathbb R,N(0,1))$; in particular $\zeta_0(h) := \mathbb E_G[h(G)]$, $\zeta_1(h) := \mathbb E_G[Gh(G)]$, and $\zeta_2(h):=\mathbb E_G[(G^2-1)h(G)]$, for $G \sim N(0,1)$.

I'm interested in a simple approximation of $T$ in terms of simple expressions in the $w_i$'s (e.g polynomial expressions). In this direction, one can obtain the following

> **(Easy case)** *If $\zeta_0(f)=0$, then*
> $$
> \|T-\mu\mu^\top\|_{op} = o_{d,\mathbb P}(1),
> \tag{1}
> $$
> *where $\mu \in \mathbb R^N$ is defined by $\mu_i := \zeta_2(f)(\|w_i\|^2-1)/2$.*

The idea is to write $T_{ij} = D\mu\mu^\top D$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with
$$
D_{ii} := \frac{\zeta_0(f_i)}{\zeta_2(f)(\|w_i\|^2-1)/2}.
$$
Further, using the assumption that $\zeta_0(f) := \mathbb E_G[f(G)] = 0$, one writes

$$
D_{ii} := \mathbb E_G\left[\frac{f(\|w_i\|G)-f(G)}{\|w_i\|-1}\right]\cdot\frac{1}{\zeta_2(f)(\|w_i\|+1)/2}
$$

One can show that
$$
\lim_{t \to 1}\dfrac{f(tG)-f(G)}{t-1} = \zeta_2(f) := \mathbb E_G[(G^2-1)f(G)].
\tag{2}
$$

> This is particularly easy to see if one assumes temporarily that $f$ is $\mathcal C^2$ around $1$ and uses a Taylor expansion combined with the observation that $\zeta_1(f') = \zeta_2(f)$. The general case is slightly more complicated.

Combining (2) with the fact that $\sup_{1 \le i \le N}||w_i|-1| = o_{d,\mathbb P}(1)$,
we obtain that $\|D-I_N\|_{op} = o_{d,\mathbb P}(1)$, from which (1) follows.

**N.B.:** Here, $o_{d,\mathbb P}(1)$ is notation for a quantity which converges to zero in probability.

---

> **Question.** *Without the condition $\zeta_0(f)=0$, is there a simple approximation of $T_0$ of the kind (1)* ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns our the problem has a simple answer, once the **easy case** has been solved (see the OP).

---

Indeed, we write $\overline{f} = f + \zeta_0(f)$, so that $\zeta_0(f) = 0$. Now, one has
$$
T = \overline{T} + v1^\top+(v1_N^\top)^\top + \zeta_0(f)^2 1_N1_N^\top,
$$
where $v = (\zeta_0(\overline{f}_i))_{i \in [N]} = (\zeta_0(f_i)-\zeta_0)_{i \in [N]}$. By the **easy case** already solved, we know that
$$
\|\overline{T}-\mu\mu^\top\|_{op} = o_{d,\mathbb P}(1).
$$

It remains localize $v1^\top$. To this end, one may write $v1^\top = D\mu 1_N^\top$, where $D$ is the $N \times N$ diagonal matrix with entries $D_{ii} = v_i /\mu_i$. As already seen before, $\|D-I_N\|_{op} = o_{d,\mathbb P}(1)$, and so $\|v1^\top - \mu 1_N^\top\|_{op} = o_{d,\mathbb P}(1)$. We deduce that

$$
\|T-uu^\top\|_{op} = o_{d,\mathbb P}(1), 
$$
where $u := \mu + \zeta_0(f)1_N$.